# Boundary Condition at the Interface of 3 Mediums in Magnetostatic?

Tags: electromagnetism, boundary-conditions, magnetostatics

we know that the boundary condition of two adjacent media in magnetostatics (assuming no surface current) is:
$$\mathbf n \times ( \mathbf H_2 - \mathbf H_1 ) = 0$$
the interface of two adjacent mediums is a surface.

but what happens in the case of three mediums with different permeabilities. their intersection becomes a line. I was thinking we use Ampere's circuital law around the intersecting line. but it seems not as easy as in the case of two mediums.